# compare user and password with md5 in txt?

Tags: php

i have a php file:

```
<?php  
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $file_name = 'hash.txt'; 
    $user = md5($_POST['user']); 
    $password = md5($_POST['password']); 
    $handle = fopen('hash.txt',"r"); 
    $read_file = file($file_name);


    if ($user == $read_file[0] and $password == $read_file[1]) { 
        echo 'correct !'; 
    } else { 
        echo 'incorrect !'; 
    } 
} else { 
    echo 'please input something'; 
}
?> 
<body> 
<form action="file_handle3.php" method="post"> 
User<input type="text" name="user"/><br/> 
Password <input type="password" name="password"/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/> 
    </body>
```

and the file txt : hash.txt the 1st line is hello the second is world

5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592

7d793037a0760186574b0282f2f435e7

i want to compare do value user input and convert them to md5 then compare with the one in txt file.i have no ideas why my code doesn't output a correct answer even when i type exactly the values (user:hello password:world).Sorry for my bad english

Comment: If you have hash in your .txt, then you should compare your md5 hashed password to the hash of the file i.e. md5($password) == $read_file[1]. Maybe if you recieve it once as a plain text and then compare the hashes would work. Also you could try to check if md5($_POST['password']) outputs really the same as in your .txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use file() every line in the file becomes an item in the array.

However, every string in that array *includes* the newline (\n). So you need to make sure you do something like...

```
trim($read_file[0],"\r\n");
```

...first.

Comment: Rather than trim the results, use the FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES flag when calling the file() function

Comment: $read_file = file($file_name, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); is available too.

Comment: Well I wish I realized that 5 years ago. Always been trimmin' ;)